# The keyword 'integrated security' is not supported on this platform

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, connection-string

I want to deployment a dotnet Core WebApplication in docker for window 
and use sqlserver ,this is my ConnectionString:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "Server=10.0.75.0; Database=WeDistributeDb; User=zac; Password=123qwe;"
  //  "Default": "DataSource=10.0.75.0\/WeDistributeDb; User=zac; Password=123qwe;"
  },
  "App": {
    "WebSiteRootAddress": "http://localhost:9903/"
  }
}
```

but when I start my image this is a error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.NotSupportedException: The keyword 'integrated security' is not supported on this platform.

What's the problem? what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported, as it says, don't run it in f5 debug attachment to docker.  I parse out a SQL AUTH user and attach that locally if i want to debug right into docker - works then.

I then use docker-compose files to replace environment variables for the deployment environments staging, production etc.  You don't really have the option for integrated security ...not that im aware in a orchestrator.

Something about .net core 2.0 maybe or.. something, not sure where i read it.